# Why isn't my useQuery resolver being called despite using 'no-cache' fetch policy?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have a use case where I need to store some basic data in localStorage and at the same time whenever that data changes, I would want my components to get re-rendered. For some other purpose, I was using useQuery and realized that using "useQuery" solves my purpose without writing a specific subscription for my query.
Using client.query, I had to write a subscription/watchQuery to continuously watch if that particular data got changed and should be reflected in all the components who use this data to get re-rendered.
But I want my data to be saved only in localStorage and not in apollo cache, so I explicitly passed fetch policy as "no-cache", it means it should never save anything in apollo cache and since nothing is getting saved in apollo cache, every time I use useQuery, it should call its client resolver which I have written.
But it is not the case, irrespective of this, my resolver is not getting called every time I use useQuery. Can somebody explain why is it so?

```
const { data: data1 } = useQuery(myQuery, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    variables: {
      shouldGetData: true,
    },
  });
```

```
Schema:

query MyQuery(
  $shouldGetData: Boolean
) {
  myQuery(
    shouldGetData: $shouldGetData
  ) @client {
    dataState
  }
}
```

```
`
Resolver:
export const clientResolvers: {
  Query: ClientSchema.Resolvers.QueryResolvers.Resolvers;
} = {
  Query: {
    myQuery: (
      _parent: unknown,
      requestedSettings,
      { localStorage }: IDataContext
      ) => getDataFromLocalStorage(requestedSettings, localStorage),
    }
  };

export const getDataFromLocalStorage = (
  {
      shouldGetData
  }: ClientSchema.Resolvers.Args.QueryMyQueryArgs,
  localStorage: ILocalStorage
): IData => {
  const dataString = localStorage.get("abc");
  const data = dataString ? safeJsonParse(dataString) : {};
  return {
   __typename: "IData",
   dataState: shouldGetData && (data.dataState ?? true),
  };
 };
```

`

Now every time I call "useQuery" it should call the resolver but it's not getting there.
Is it storing data in apollo cache and reading every time from there? If yes, why? I have used fetch policy as "no-cache".